# Client -> Rails -> MySQL -> Socket.io | Good Idea?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redis, socket.io, chat

I'm working on a web app that involves managing users with a classic Ruby on Rails with MySQL setup.

This app also has chatbox elements. Socket.io seems like the right tool for the job, and I was hoping for some review on whether this process seems like a good idea:

1. Client sends chat message JSON to Rails controller.
2. Rails controller authenticates client and appends chat message to chat conversation JSON in MySQL server.
3. Rails controller sends response to client telling it MySQL server has been updated.
4. Client starts event on Socket.io Node server triggering it to send out updated chat conversation JSON to all clients (sockets).

EDIT: Steps 3 and 4 were updated. We go back to the client to speak to the Socket.io server after the Rails server because the Socket.io client-side library is good for triggering socket events. It also means not downloading an extra gem to mediate Rails-Socket.io communication. Let me know if this is a bad design choice.

This is the most complex project I've worked on, and I'm highly appreciative of any wisdom you guys could give me before I dive in.

I'm concerned about:

1. If I notify the Socket.io server to send out updated conversations the moment the user hits send, could it be possible that Rails won't finish authenticating and storing the new data in the MySQL server before Socket.io queries for it? Would it be awkward to delay Socket.io's query for a second after the user hits send? (I believe adding timers generally means I'm doing something wrong)

EDIT: I think I have the answer to the above after reading Mr. Yoshiji's comment. I'll send a response back to the client from the Rails server, and then the client will trigger the Socket.io server to update all other clients' chat. It will all be sequential with no race conditions or timer nonsense.

2. Would MongoDB or Redis be better than MySQL for chat conversation storage? I say MongoDB because the chat would all be JSON, and Redis seems to be used in tutorials and offer hooks for Socket.io, negating the above problem. On the downside, I'm unclear on what exactly Redis is, and I don't like the idea of adding a fourth server to this project.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The regular HTTP requests, which can be JSON type, works like the following: Client sends a **request** to the web server which send back a **response** (the client request always expect a response from the server). The Socket is different, there is a continuous connexion between the client and the server, and usually event-driven. You can either use Socket.io for your chat, OR you can use a simple JS script which will (http) request the server every X seconds to grab the new stuff.

Comment: About your concerns: **concern #1**: the message sent by the end-user will be transported via Socket.io to the web server, which will handle the event and respond via Socket.io again, so it is all about the event chain (callbacks) you define. The message cannot be sent via HTTP and expect Socket.io to send a response (that could be possible but way too complicated). **concern #2**: Unless you expect thousands of input/output every seconds, any kind of DB is good. MongoDB might be better (performance-wise) but more complex to implement. One advice: stick to RDBMS or NoSQL, don't try to switch.